# Finding "actual" characters (graphemes) in a QString

Tags: qt, unicode, utf-16

Let's say I have a QString that may consist of any Unicode characters, and I want to iterate through its characters or count them. And by "characters" I mean what the user perceives as such (so roughly equivalent to "glyphs") and not simply QChars (16-bit Unicode characters). Some "actual" characters are built of several QChars (surrogate pairs; base character + combining marks). For some combining characters I might get away with normalizing the string to create composite characters, but that does not always help.

Have I overlooked a built-in function that splits a QString into "actual" characters?

Or if I have to parse it myself, is this the structure (in EBNF) or am I missing something?

```
character = ((high_surrogate, low_surrogate) | base_character), {combining_mark}
```

(with `base_character` being every QChar that is not a surrogate or combining character)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more research I found the term for "actual character", **grapheme**, and with it the Qt class for finding grapheme boundaries: **QTextBoundaryFinder**.

Comment: Here is a code sample that uses `QTextBoundaryFinder`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49558718/257299

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the combining marks, but for the surrogate pairs, I think you can use [QString::toUcs4()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#toUcs4) which should return a 32-bit Unicode representation of your string.

Comment: QString::toUcs4() returns 2 value for surrogate pair

Comment: QString::toUcs4() returns 2 value for surrogate pair in Qt4 but only 1 value for Qt5. So your answer is partially correct.

Comment: My bad. Qt4 returns wrong vector size. So for string "" it returns

8 
"1f600" 
"1f600" 
"1f600" 
"1f600" 
"0" 
"0" 
"0" 
"0"