# Get QString length (in characters, not bytes)

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I need to get the actual character count (not byte count), similar to what is output when getting string length in V8.

This is necessary for use with Twitter, which goes by character count no matter the language used, even with UTF-8 (it does NOT go by byte length).

Ex:

in chrome/chromium js console, or in nodejs:

```
> "Schöne Grüße".length
< 12
```

In Qt 4.8.2, trying `QString someStr = "Schöne Grüße"; cout << someStr.length()` will output 15, which is not what I'm aiming for.

Comment: I wonder what Twitter does with combining diacriticals - does it count those in it's "character count"? 8-P

Comment: ... oh [they don't](https://dev.twitter.com/basics/counting-characters)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to construct it using the specific [`fromUtf8` static method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf8):

```
QString s = QString::fromUtf8("Schöne Grüße");
```

Comment: Point, that was it, thank you.  Hope that it'll work fine with japanese and other unicode chars, but we'll see. :)

Comment: Qstring is internally utf16 but handles converting to/from utf8

Comment: If you then use `QString::length`, then you'll get 2 for the string of `u8""`, which is wrong as an answer to the OP.

Comment: @Ruslan, I've just tested this in both Qt4 and Qt5, and in both cases, with and without the u8, I get a length of 1.

Comment: Did you use `#` or `` in your test? They are not the same: the former is U+0x0023, while the latter is U+0x10139.

Comment: Ah fair enough.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. It won't work if you fall out of the utf16 range.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to count grapheme clusters (i.e. the user-perceived characters) instead of code units, you need [`QTextBoundaryFinder`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextboundaryfinder.html). Here's an example of use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QTextBoundaryFinder>
#include <QString>

int main()
{
    const QString s=QString::fromUtf8(u8"abc\U00010139def\U00010102g");
    std::cout << "String: \"" << s.toStdString() << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "Code unit count       : " << s.length() << "\n";

    QTextBoundaryFinder tbf(QTextBoundaryFinder::Grapheme, s);
    int count=0;
    while(tbf.toNextBoundary()!=-1)
        ++count;
    std::cout << "Grapheme cluster count: " << count << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
String: "abcdefg"
Code unit count       : 11
Grapheme cluster count: 9
```