# Get QString length in bytes (not characters)

Tags: qt, text, size, codec, qstring

I need to solve the problem opposite to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999127/get-qstring-length-in-characters-not-bytes). I have QString with non-ascii symbols.
For example:
`Schöne Grüße`

How to get the length of the string in bytes for UTF8 case? It should be 15.
I have tried conversion to `ByteArray`, to `Latin1`, `ASCII` but length is always the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use ::toUtf8() and append it to a QByteArray. Then you can get the length using .size().

```
QString s = "Schöne Grüße";
QByteArray bytes = s.toUtf8();
int length = bytes.size(); //Number of bytes
```

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qbytearray.html#size

Comment: toUtf8 doesnt have parameter!!

Comment: Correct, it does not.

Answer (score -3):

http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:strlen

The C Standard API strlen() returns the number of bytes in a null terminated string, not including the null terminator.