# How to count perceived characters in Qt 6?

Tags: qt, emoji, qt6

I tried several accepted answers here including:

- QTextBoundaryFinder tbf(QTextBoundaryFinder::Grapheme, text);
- QRegularExpression("\X");
- text.toUcs4().size();

None of them gives a size of one for ⌨️. How can I properly count the perceived character count?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the[`QTextBoundaryFinder` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49558718/20143744).
My guess as to why it does not work for you is that you initialize your text variable with something like:

```cpp
QString text = QStringLiteral("⌨️");
```

If that is it, your compiler should be giving you a warning, such as [C4566](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4566?view=msvc-170). I recommend you try to spot the message during compilation before you use the solution below.

---

Solution: the correct way to initialize `text` is:

```cpp
QString text = QString::fromStdWString(L"⌨️");
```

I suppose from your question that you already know it but just in case (and for other people reading my answer), be careful not to simply use `text.length()` and other methods.
Indeed, that would return:

- ⌨: 1 (`\u2328`)
- ⌨️: 2 (`\u2328` `\uFE0F`)

The reason why I mention it is that, unlike on the website, my IDE shows the very same thing for the keyboard character or its [variant form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_form_(Unicode)) (the one with `\uFE0F`, used in your question).